# How to trigger Jenkins rebuild of existing PR if a SNAPSHOT dependency is rebuilt?

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

TL;DR;

How do I trigger rebuild of a PR to `master` branch in `my-server`, when some other PR in some other repo (some `common-lib`) is merged into `master`? Where `my-server` depends on `common-lib`.

All SNAPSHOT versions, not tagged/versioned/release artifacts.

---

We use Jenkins with BB server to build our Java/maven repos. We follow git-flow kind of branching strategy, so that all artifacts built from our `master` (development branch) are SNAPSHOT versions.

Say I have

- two repos in my project `my-server` and `common-lib`, where `my-server` depends on `common-lib`
- two Jenkins jobs (one for each repo) that build all PRs (source branches) and all commits to `master`.

Steps:

- I open a PR-1 open in `my-server` repo, from branch `feature/abc` to `master`.

  - This triggers a build of the PR and it is built with latest/master of `common-lib`. It's green.
  - PR-1 is NOT yet merged.
- someone opens a PR-2 in `common-lib`, merges it to `master`. Now we have a new version of latest/master `common-lib`. This is not compatible with `my-server` -- `feature/abc`.
- I merge PR-1, which triggers build of `my-server`'s `master`. This fails.

Question:
If I can trigger a rebuild of PR-1 after PR-2 is merged, then my merge-checks (needs a green build) will mark PR-1 as "needs work". How do I do this?

Thank you!

---

I've read following and many others:

- [How to trigger jenkins maven job with multiple branches when a SNAPSHOT dependency is built?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218050/how-to-trigger-jenkins-maven-job-with-multiple-branches-when-a-snapshot-dependen)
- [How to force Jenkins to rebuild a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314296/how-to-force-jenkins-to-rebuild-a-branch)
- [How to trigger jenkins build upon bitbucket pull request merged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37960358/how-to-trigger-jenkins-build-upon-bitbucket-pull-request-merged)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably code your way out of this specific situation by manually retriggering all PR checks for every PR in progress in `my-server` repo on every merge to `common-lib` repo, but "pushing" changes from dependencies into your app makes for a chaotic workflow. That's why it's bad practice to use the main branch name to reference your dependency - there is no way for consumers to opt out of incompatible changes. Once you start referencing release branches (or tags, or specific commits - depends on how much control you want to have and how much work you are willing to do) - you have something to work with. In your case `master` in `my-server` will be updated to reference a new version of `common-lib` and that can re-trigger PR checks. I'm not familiar with BB, but in GitHub it's not the default behavior, since `master` usually moves fast and re-checking PRs would create heavy load on your CI, but it can be done.

Comment: Thanks, that (DIY) is what we figured as well. Would've been nice to have some plugin/DSL to trigger.